# Get R to print output of a for loop

Tags: r, loops, output

This seems like a straightforward thing, but I can't get it to work!

I have a loop that looks like this:

```
PCPHENO<-merge(PCAEVEC,PHENOTYPE)
for (i in 1:5) {
    summary(lm(Outcome ~ PCPHENO[,i+1], PCPHENO))
}
```

where PCPHENO looks something like this:

```
ID PC1 PC2 PC3 PC4 PC5 Outcome
Bob 0.1 0.4 -0.3 0.4 0.3 1
Carl -0.1 0.3 -0.2 0.2 0.2 1
Dan 0.6 0.2 0.3 -0.4 0.2 2
Ed 0.6 0.4 -0.3 0.4 0.3 2
Frank 0.2 0.4 -0.3 0.4 0.3 2
George 0.5 0.4 -0.3 0.4 0.3 1
```

When I run the command *summary(...)* alone, it works fine and outputs data. However, when I run this loop, it appears to wok fine but there is no output.

I'm sure I'm just missing a command, but I don't know what it is!

Comment: `print` prints things to the console. When you type things at the console, `print` is called implicitly.

Comment: @joran Where do I need to add print? I tried in front of summary in the loop, but ti doesn't work (neither does write or save)

Comment: `print(summary(...))`.

Comment: Issue with my console and print -this works